# How to convert ISO date and time format to "DD Mon YYYY hh:mm:ss"?

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have a variable like this,

```
var date = "2016-04-07T03:03:03Z";
```

How do I convert it to a time format like this `6 Apr 2016, 8:03:03 PM`in the local timezone using JavaScript/jQuery?

Comment: +1 simply because you know an ISO date format when you see one. Waaay too many of these date/time questions don't understand standard formats.

Comment: LOL :D Thanks for the +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit 2021-02-26**: Consider using a more modern library such as https://date-fns.org/

Original:

As you want to parse it with a timezone and then format the output, I'd strongly suggest using [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) which is a well used library for time and date manipulation:

The code would look something like this:

```
var date = "2016-04-07T03:03:03Z";
console.log(moment(date).format('D MMM YYYY, h:mm:ss A')); 
// "7 Apr 2016, 5:03:03 AM"
```

Comment: moment.js is in maintenance mode and will not be developed further. They recommend using date https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/

Answer (score 1):

Solution using `Date.prototype.toLocaleDateString()` function:

```
var date_str = "2016-04-07T03:03:03Z",
    options = { year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day: 'numeric', hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit', second: '2-digit'},
    formatted = (new Date(date_str)).toLocaleDateString('en-US', options),
    date_parts = formatted.substring(0, formatted.indexOf(",")).split(" ").reverse().join(" ");

var formatted_date = date_parts + formatted.substr(formatted.indexOf(",") + 1);

console.log(formatted_date);
```

The output will look like the following(according to your locale):

```
7 Apr 2016, 6:03:03 AM
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var date = "2016-04-07T03:03:03Z";
var myDate = new Date(date);

console.log(myDate);
```

> Thu Apr 07 2016 05:03:03 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)

The `new Date(date)` convert in the local timezone

If you want more control over the value you can also format the date, see [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) for more info

Answer (score 0):

I've tried something that might help you.

**EDIT: Updated my code snippet to format military time into standard time**

```js
function formatDate ( today ) {
  var newDateItems = new Array();
  var dateItems = String(today).split(" ");
  dateItems.forEach(function(item, index){
   if (index > 0 && index < 5) {
      if (index == 4){
        item = getStandardTime(item);
      }
      newDateItems.push(item);
    }
  });
  return newDateItems.join(" ");
}
//To format military time into standard time
function getStandardTime( time ) {
  time = time.split(":");
  var hh = Number(time[0]);
  var mm = Number(time[1]);
  var ss = Number(time[2]);
  var timeValue = "";
  if (hh > 12) timeValue += hh - 12;
  else timeValue += hh;
  
  if (mm < 10) timeValue += ":0" + mm;
  else timeValue += ":" + mm
  
  if (ss < 10) timeValue += ":0" + ss;
  else timeValue += ":" + ss
  
  timeValue += (hh >= 12) ? " PM" : " AM"; 
  return timeValue
  
}
var dateToday = new Date();
document.write(formatDate(dateToday));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that also uses `type-script`, and also adds **0** in front of the minute and hour if it is one digit.

```
function convertISODateToTimeFormat(ISODate: string) {
      const newDateObj = new Date(ISODate);
      const toMonth = newDateObj.getMonth() + 1;
      const toYear = newDateObj.getFullYear();
      const toDate = newDateObj.getDate();
      const toHours = newDateObj.getHours();
      const toHoursProcessed = (toHours < 10 ? '0' : '') + toHours;
      const toMin = newDateObj.getMinutes();
      const toMinProcessed = (toMin < 10 ? '0' : '') + toMin;
      const dateTemplate = `${toDate}.${toMonth}.${toYear} ${toHoursProcessed}:${toMinProcessed}`;
      // console.log(dateTemplate)
      return dateTemplate;
    }
    convertISODateToTimeFormat('2019-08-07T02:01:49.499Z')
```