# How to change default datepicker format from mm/dd/yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: javascript, html, datepicker

I have a jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/43a92668/)

```
$(function() {
  $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
```

I am very new to coding and can't figure out how to make the date format day month as inputting data is being processed by the button thinking it's the other way around and causing all sorts of errors.

Secondly I want to know how to combine and place into an iframe or something that will allow me to insert it into our website without it changing other things as this code is very messy and was extracted from another of our websites.

If someone could explain exactly how to do this I would be very grateful as i've read other responses to this question but am unsure how to make it work with my jfiddle.

Comment: you can check answers in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36478453/how-to-convert-iso-date-and-time-format-to-dd-mon-yyyy-hhmmss

Comment: Thank you, ill try to understand how this can work with mine.

Comment: Install it in the new location.  To format day/month add this:

Comment: $(function() {
  $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'dd MM yy'
  });
});

Comment: Thank you Nathaniel for your help!